# How does execution policy work for sequential traversal algorithms in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, c++17

C++ 17 added the [execution policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) to many algorithms.

For algorithms like [for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) it's easy to imagine how the implementation of the parallelized version would work: instead of invoking the provided function sequentially from first to last, partition the range and execute the function in parallel for each partition.

But for algorithms that imply sequential traversal to the first occurrence, like [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), what would the parallelized version do?

Comment: You can still divide the range with `find` and select the closest subrange that succeeds.

Comment: I imagine that you would interleave the partitions, then then once you find at a position you'll have to coordinate with the other workers to continue only for smaller positions, otherwise stop. This way one would hope that the gain through parallelism would not be weighted too much by the additional work past the first occurrence. But is this what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's not specified, beyond the general properties that the *ExecutionPolicy* permits.

This allows a platform to choose between multiple strategies if it so wishes, e.g. with profile guided optimisation.